# Send response after email send node express

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have the following method for `/signup` route:

```
const {sendEmail} = require("../lib/email");

exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
       //validate request and save user in DB
    
        let content = {
          activateLink: "link to activate email",
        };

      await sendEmail(email, "Verification OTP", "otp", content, next);

      res.status(201).json({
       message: "User created successfully !",
       userData: {
       _id: result._id.toString(),
        email: result.email,
       },
      });
  }
    catch (err) {
        if (!err.statusCode) {
          err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(err);
  }
};
```

Method for sending email:

```
const path = require("path");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const hbs = require("nodemailer-express-handlebars");
const viewPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/views");
const partialsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/partials");
const config = require("../config");

exports.sendEmail = async (to, subject, viewName, content, next) => {
    try {
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(config.mailConfig);
      const handlebarsOptions = {
        viewEngine: {
          extName: ".handlebars",
          layoutsDir: viewPath,
          defaultLayout: false,
          partialsDir: partialsPath,
        },
        viewPath: viewPath,
        extName: ".handlebars",
      };
  
      transporter.use("compile", hbs(handlebarsOptions));
  
      const mailOptions = {
        from: "noreply@admin.com", // Update from email
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        template: viewName,
        context: content,
      };
  
      let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  };
```

With the above code blocks. I'm able to send email to newly registered user when I send post request. But postman keeps sending request and doesn't get any response status and message after email is sent.

I think code execution is not getting out of `sendEmail` method. Adding `return true;` after `console.log("Message sent: %s", info.response);` is also not helping at all.

I would be thankful if anyone could help me to figure out the solution.

Comment: The signup function declared in the first code is a middleware right?

Comment: Yes.  It is used as following.

`router.post("/user/signup",UserController.signup);`

Comment: the smtp protocol is somewhat slow ~1 or 2 secs min, the user doesn't need to know when the email was sent so you shouldn't need to wait. ideally, you should send emails (or any long running thing) in a task queue running on a separate process or use [worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)'s, if the email fails to send, mark as not sent and try again (if not bounce/max quota etc) and mark the users email as not verified etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LATEST EDIT** In the comments you mention it is middleware, which would be correct with the function signature of (req, res, next).

But when I look at the line you posted in the comments `router.post("/user/signup",UserController.signup);` it is a normal route where the signature should be (req, res).

So could you try:

```js
const {sendEmail} = require("../lib/email");

exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
  try {
       //validate request and save user in DB

        let content = {
          activateLink: "link to activate email",
        };

      const result = await sendEmail(email, "Verification OTP", "otp", content);

      res.status(201).json({
       message: "User created successfully !",
       userData: {
       _id: result._id.toString(),
        email: result.email,
       },
      });
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.log(`Something went wrong sending activation mail`, err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

```js
import { rejects } from "assert";

exports.sendEmail = async (to, subject, viewName, content) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(config.mailConfig);
      const handlebarsOptions = {
        viewEngine: {
          extName: ".handlebars",
          layoutsDir: viewPath,
          defaultLayout: false,
          partialsDir: partialsPath,
        },
        viewPath: viewPath,
        extName: ".handlebars",
      };

      transporter.use("compile", hbs(handlebarsOptions));

      const mailOptions = {
        from: "noreply@admin.com", // Update from email
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        template: viewName,
        context: content,
      };

      let info = transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Message sent: %s", result.messageId);
            resolve(result);
       });
    });
};
```

---

Which version of nodemailer are you using? Pre 6.4.1 does not return a Promise so you need to use a callback then.

With callback the code will look something like this:

```js
const {sendEmail} = require("../lib/email");

exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
       //validate request and save user in DB
    
        let content = {
          activateLink: "link to activate email",
        };

      const result = await sendEmail(email, "Verification OTP", "otp", content, next);

      res.status(201).json({
       message: "User created successfully !",
       userData: {
       _id: result._id.toString(),
        email: result.email,
       },
      });
  }
    catch (err) {
        if (!err.statusCode) {
          err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(err);
  }
};
```

```js
import { rejects } from "assert";

exports.sendEmail = async (to, subject, viewName, content) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(config.mailConfig);
      const handlebarsOptions = {
        viewEngine: {
          extName: ".handlebars",
          layoutsDir: viewPath,
          defaultLayout: false,
          partialsDir: partialsPath,
        },
        viewPath: viewPath,
        extName: ".handlebars",
      };
  
      transporter.use("compile", hbs(handlebarsOptions));
  
      const mailOptions = {
        from: "noreply@admin.com", // Update from email
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        template: viewName,
        context: content,
      };
  
      let info = transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Message sent: %s", result.messageId);
            resolve(result);
       });
    });
};
```

And you need to return the result (info) from `let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);` to the `signup` method.

```
        _id: result._id.toString(), <-- result will be undefined here
        email: result.email,        <-- result will be undefined here
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion. I'm currently;y using `nodemailer v6.7.5`

I've tried your method with Promise. But the result is still the same. And `result._id.toString()` , `result.email` is coming from user object. Which I removed here to keep the code section short.

Comment: Have you tried placing a console.log after the `await sendMail(......`? And does this show up?

Comment: I've will edit my answer. I have another idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine.
Since we're missing some of the code,
I can only think one of the following may have happened:

1. Express failed stringifying result.email (Circular JSON)
2. The transporter.sendMail() promise does not resolve (Does the "Message sent:..." log show?)

Can you post console logs?

Regardless, I would suggest separating your sendEmail function from the responsibility of catching and passing the error to the next function, since the whole function is surrounded with one try catch block, you may as well let the sendEmail throw and catch it as you're already doing.
Now sendEmail doesn't have to be called by an express route / middleware

Comment: Yes. Message sent log is being printed. Here a copy of one instance.

`Message sent: <125a62e8-a6ba-f1b2-63b1-874858a89a5f@admin.com>`

I'm also getting email in my inbox

Comment: Would be really helpful if we had more insight, perhaps the console output (If there's an error stack or message) or the way you connect the route to express